# How to put "if the function has been called this many times" in Python?

Tags: python, kivy

So I'm designing a hangman game using Python and Kivy and I want to add a win/lose option.

one of the functions I've defined is Button_pressed which hides the button if it's been pressed but I want the function man_is_hung() to have something that says "if the button has been pressed 6 times, show "game over"."

Would someone please help me?

```
 def button_pressed(button):
        for (letter, label) in CurrentWord:
            if (letter.upper() == button.text): label.text=letter 
        button.text=" " # hide the letter to indicate it's been tried

def man_is_hung():
    if button_pressed(button)
```

Comment: You will need to preserve the state either in an object member or `global`.

Answer (score 5):

Use a [decorator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators):

**Example:**

```
class count_calls(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.count = 0
        self.func = func
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # if self.count == 6 : do something
        self.count += 1
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

@count_calls
def func(x, y):
    return x + y
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> for _ in range(4): func(0, 0)
>>> func.count
4
>>> func(0, 0)
0
>>> func.count
5
```

In py3.x you can use `nonlocal` to achieve the same thing using a function instead of a class:

```
def count_calls(func):
    count = 0
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        nonlocal count
        if count == 6:
            raise TypeError('Enough button pressing')
        count += 1
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@count_calls
def func(x, y):
    return x + y
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> for _ in range(6):func(1,1)
>>> func(1, 1)
    ...
    raise TypeError('Enough button pressing')
TypeError: Enough button pressing
```

Comment: This is a pretty novel idea. I can't tell if it's a good one or not.

Comment: This is probably the number one thing I use decorators for (bookkeeping on functions). It makes your code way cleaner and is very easy to remove/change.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to have static variables in functions that doesn't involve globals or classes:

```
def foobar():
    foobar.counter = getattr(foobar, 'counter', 0)
    foobar.counter += 1
    return foobar.counter

for i in range(5):
    print foobar()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store the button as a class like so:

```
class button_pressed(Object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.num_calls = 0

    def __call__(self, button):
        self.num_calls += 1
        if self.num_calls > 6:
            print "Game over."
            return None
        else:
           # Your regular function stuff goes here.
```

This is basically a manual decorator, and while it might be a bit complicated for what you are trying to do this is an easy way to do bookkeeping on a function.

Really, the correct way to do this kind of thing is to use a decorator that takes a parameter for the number of times you want the function to be able to be called and then applies the above pattern automatically.

Edit: Ahh! hcwhsa beat me to it. His solution is the more general one I was talking about above.

Answer (score 0):

ummmm

```
num_presses = 0
def button_pressed(button):
    global num_presses
    num_presses += 1
    if num_presses > X:
         print "YOU LOSE SUCKA!!!"
    for (letter, label) in CurrentWord:
        if (letter.upper() == button.text): label.text=letter 
    button.text=" " # hide the letter to indicate it's been tried
```

would be one way of doing it ... Im kind of suprised you have made it this far without knowing how to save simple states.